# After recover sshd_config on my VPS my TeamSpeak 3 client can't connect with server

Tags: ssh, port

I'm destroy my default sshd_config file in /etc/ssh/ on my VPS and I'm recover this to default one.
After this I'm trying to connect with my TS3 server on this same VPS.
OS says me TS is ON and everything is fine but... no... :(

```
[root@vps75870 ~]# service teamspeak restart  
Stopping the TeamSpeak 3 server..done  
Starting the TeamSpeak 3 server  
TeamSpeak 3 server started, for details please view the log file  
[root@vps75870 ~]# service teamspeak status  
Server is running .
```

When I'm trying to connect with it I received: <21:34:29> Failed to connect to server.
I'm not edited any ports etc.

Any advice?

Comment: "for details please view the log file".  Other than that, check `netstat -nat` to verify the port is open for teamspeak.

Answer (score 0):

Change you made in sshd_config shouldn't have influenced TeamPass. Problems you are seeing are result of something else, unless you are using SSH tunnel to connect to TeamServer.

Anyway, one thing you can try is to enable following setting in your sshd_config:

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
X11Forwarding yes
```

and see if it helps. Don't forget to restart ssh after applying changes.